# Order posts by Last comment date and the created data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have Posts table with two attributes "last_comment" and "created" and I save the unix time stamp date , I want to order the posts by the created date and also the last_comment Descending .

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from table order by last_comment desc, created
```

Comment: `created desc` too, as per one of the OP's comments

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table
order by created, last_comment desc
```

Comment: How does it not work? You'll need to add the `desc` to the columns you want to order in that direction. Default is ascending, so just add `desc` to the relevant ones.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to sort rows in MySql

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sorting-rows.html

Comment: I know how to sort the rows , but I want first to order the posts by created date descending and if a user add a comment to a specific post it should be the first post in the set .

`order by created, last_comment desc`

doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
  FROM table
 ORDER BY created DESC, last_comment DESC
```